# how to reset styles in vue carousel?

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I am using vue carousel and I want to change tge color of the pagination dots' borders. I don't know how and if it's even possible. I looked up the style of this buttons in dev tools and tried to rewrite the style. But nothing works

Answer (score 1):

`vue-carousel` has [two properties](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel#configuration) that control the color of the dots:

- `paginationColor` - (default: `#000000`) The fill color of the active pagination dot. Any valid CSS color is accepted.
- `paginationActiveColor` - (default: `#efefef`) The fill color of pagination dots. Any valid CSS color is accepted.

For example:

```html
<carousel paginationColor="gray" paginationActiveColor="red">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-pagination-dot-colors-in-vue-carousel-zwnwn?file=/src/App.vue:28-94)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your global CSS

```css
.v-carousel__controls__item{
    color: #FFC400 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-around that can give you full control over the dots and their appearance with pure CSS, using pseudo-elements. Make the existing dots transparent, and use ::after to create new dots that you can style as you like.

```css
    .VueCarousel-dot {
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent !important;

      &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: gray;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
      }

      &--active::after {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }
```

This is not an ideal solution, however the provided options for styling dots in Vue Carousel are quite limited, and if you have a strict style guide to follow, this solution can give you the control you need.